# How to quickly check if a git pull command is successful?

Tags: git, version-control, status, git-pull

I wrote a bash script to loop through all git folders and do a `git pull`. The issue is there are a lot of folders, and the `git pull` command generates a lot of logs for each of them, so that I have to skim through the logs and check if any of them had failures (e.g: some might need a `git reset` prior to the pull)
Is there a way to get kind of "success" or "failure" state of `git pull` result, then it'd be more concise in the logs, and I can just focus on those that failed and treat them separately.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can check if git commands were succesful or not.

After a failed `git pull`, the exit status would be non-zero, you can check it like this in a shell script :

```
if /usr/bin/git pull; then
    echo "OK"
else
    echo "Not Ok"
fi
```